# Starting a simple python thread on Django init

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have just now started to work with django. On my development environment I use to the start the django server using:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

and my web application is working as expected still I have many errors with that too... But as of now I want to run a background thread on the server init and I need some guidance.

Here is the thread code which I am trying to add:

```
def synchronized(L):
    def lock_around(f):
        def locked(*a, **k):
            with L:
                return f(*a, **k)
        locked.__name__ = f.__name__
        locked.__doc__ = f.__doc__
        return locked
    return lock_around


class ProcessMsgQueue:

    def __init__(self):
        try:
            print "jaojdajdoaj"
            self.dataCounter = 0
            self.errorCounter = 0
            self.setupQueueTable()
            self.wrapperFuns = structureWrapper.WrapperClass()
            msgStruct = MsgStruct()
            self.VerifyMsgQueue()
        except:
            raise

    def setupQueueTable(self):
        self.hash_object = QueueHandler("queue_details")
        self.hash_object.EnableListener()
        self.hash_object.createNewHashRef()
        self.hash_object.create("dataMsgQueue")
        self.hash_object.create("errorMsgQueue")

    @synchronized(lock)     
    def pendMessage(self):
        print "pendMsg"
        try:
            res_mq = posix_ipc.MessageQueue(RESPONSE_QUEUE_NAME)
            res_msg = None
            res_msg,t_size = res_mq.receive()
            #print res_msg.encode('hex')
            return res_msg
        except Exception as e:
            print e
            raise
        finally:
            res_mq.close()

    def VerifyMsgQueue(self):
        while(self.hash_object.Queuelisten):
            try:
                posixQueueMessage=self.pendMessage()
                if not posixQueueMessage == None:
                    msgStruct = None
                    msgStruct = MsgStruct()
                    self.wrapperFuns.memCopy(posixQueueMessage,msgStruct)
                    if(msgStruct.msgType == palMsgType["DOOR_OPEN_INSERVICE_MSG"]):
                        print "Added Error to hastable"
                        self.hash_object.set("errorMsgQueue",self.errorCounter,msgStruct.msgBuf)
                    else:
                        print "Added Data to hastable"
                        self.hash_object.set("dataMsgQueue",msgStruct.msgType,msgStruct.msgBuf)
                    posixQueueMessage=None
            except:
                raise
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Mucking about with threads in a web serving environment is usually the wrong thing to do. What's your actual use case? Also, if you really want us to help, you'll have to be more specific than "I have many errors".

Comment: @DanielRoseman : i am trying to build an interprocess communication application .. where the flow will be like this ... html/js -- > django --> python will post in POSIX IPC queue --> C application read n process --> C application will post messages another IPC channel (and this post might occur any time)..so to monitor i need a thread in my django APP (just like a background process.

Comment: Really? And have you thought about how that update will get back to the user on the front end? This seems very over-engineered, it sounds like message queues will be a much simpler and more appropriate solution.

Comment: @DanielRoseman : "I have many errors" in this part i have simple page redirection issues..but since threading is my priority i ll close this issue first and next try  to understand the re direction part..

Comment: @DanielRoseman : yes we are using message queues only. the object posted by the mesage queue will be structure where we de-compile the structure and return to JSON and process the rest

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to call your init code from end of `wsgi.py` file. It will be executed once at start of server.

Comment: from whicn class wsgi.py is invoked ..will it be invoked from settings.py – Ragav 2 hours ago